# Does a FlowableOperator inherently supports backpressure?

Tags: rx-java2, backpressure

I've implemented an `FlowableOperator` as described in the RxJava2 wiki (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Writing-operators-for-2.0#operator-targeting-lift) except that I perform some testing in the `onNext()` operation something like that:

```java
public final class MyOperator implements FlowableOperator<Integer, Integer> {

...

static final class Op implements FlowableSubscriber<Integer>, Subscription {

    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer v) {
        if (v % 2 == 0) {
          child.onNext(v * v);
        }  
    }
   ...
  }
}
```

This operator is part of a chain where I have a `Flowable` created with a backpressure drop. In essence, it looks almost like this:

```java
Flowable.<Integer>create(emitter -> myAction(), DROP)
        .filter(v -> v > 2)
        .lift(new MyOperator())
        .subscribe(n -> doSomething(n));
```

I've met the following issue:

- backpressure occurs, so `doSomething(n)` cannot handle the upcoming upstream
- items are dropped due to the Backpressure strategy chosen
- but doSomething(n) never receives back new item after the drop has been performed and while doSomething(n) was ready to deal with new items

Reading back the excellent blog post http://akarnokd.blogspot.fr/2015/05/pitfalls-of-operator-implementations.html of David Karnok, it's seems that I need to add a `request(1)` in the `onNext()` method. But that was with RxJava1...

So, my question is: is this fix enough in RxJava2 to deal with my backpressure issue? Or do my operator have to implement all the stuff about Atomics, drain stuff described in https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Writing-operators-for-2.0#atomics-serialization-deferred-actions to properly handle my backpressure issue?

Note: I've added the `request(1)` and it seems to work. But I can't figure out whether it's enough or whether my operator needs the tricky stuff of queue-drain and atomics.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does a FlowableOperator inherently supports backpressure?

`FlowableOperator` is an interface that is called for a given downstream `Subscriber` and should return a new `Subscriber` that wraps the downstream and modulates the Reactive Streams events passing in one or both directions. Backpressure support is the responsibility of the `Subscriber` implementation, not this particular functional interface. It could have been `Function<Subscriber, Subscriber>` but a separate named interface was deemed more usable and less prone to overload conflicts.

> need to add a request(1) in the onNext() [...]
>   But I can't figure out whether it's enough or whether my operator needs the tricky stuff of queue-drain and atomics.

Yes, you have to do that in RxJava 2 as well. Since RxJava 2's `Subscriber` is not a class, it doesn't have v1's convenience `request` method. You have to save the `Subscription` in `onSubscribe` and call `upstream.request(1)` on the appropriate path in `onNext`. For your case, it should be quite enough.

I've updated the wiki with a new section explaining this case explicitly:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Writing-operators-for-2.0#replenishing

```java
final class FilterOddSubscriber implements FlowableSubscriber<Integer>, Subscription {

    final Subscriber<? super Integer> downstream;

    Subscription upstream;

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        if (upstream != null) {
            s.cancel();
        } else {
            upstream = s;                    // <-------------------------
            downstream.onSubscribe(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer item) {
        if (item % 2 != 0) {
           downstream.onNext(item);
        } else {
           upstream.request(1);              // <-------------------------
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void request(long n) {
        upstream.request(n);
    }

    // the rest omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the wiki update! So, from my understanding adding `upstream.request(1)` would be enough to support backpressure in my case.

It wouldn't be enough if the downstream would request more than 1 element. In this case, one would have to implement the drain-queue stuff described in the wiki. Am I right?

Comment: It depends on the operator's behavior, not the request pattern of the downstream. If you drop 1 item, you have to request 1 more item from upstream in this middle operator. Queue-drain comes into play when there is an async boundary, not in your plain sequential operator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to do the tricky stuff...

I would avoid writing operators, except if you are very sure what you are doing? Nearly everything can be achieved with the default operators...

> Writing operators, source-like (fromEmitter) or intermediate-like
>   (flatMap) has always been a hard task to do in RxJava. There are many
>   rules to obey, many cases to consider but at the same time, many
>   (legal) shortcuts to take to build a well performing code. Now writing
>   an operator specifically for 2.x is 10 times harder than for 1.x. If
>   you want to exploit all the advanced, 4th generation features, that's
>   even 2-3 times harder on top (so 30 times harder in total).

There is the tricky stuff explained: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Writing-operators-for-2.0